# YouTube channel name is not parsed

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I try to parse the channel name, it displays an empty list

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCurxArcVECR3ZKBG1Mo9nDg')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
item = soup.select('#text')
print(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCurxArcVECR3ZKBG1Mo9nDg')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('meta')['content'])
```

---

Explaination:

- `<meta>` is a tag in the `<html>`
- `content` is a attribute of the `meta` tag

When you give:

```
print(soup.find('meta'))
```

You get the first meta tag which is the channel name.

```
<meta content="Matthew Chávez" name="title"/>
```

This is then traversed like a dictionary, `content` being the key.

Comment: Oh, it really happened! What do "meta" and "content" mean?